# One column, two names, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I am trying to standardize column naming in my mysql database. During the transition, I need to be able to access a column of a given table using both the new and the old column names.
Specifically, these two queries need to return the same results.

```
SELECT `old` FROM `table`;
SELECT `new` FROM `table`;
```

Also, any new data inserted into the new column name should be available through the old column name; and viceversa.

Comment: Why don't you migrate them both over to the same column name?

Comment: Two different applications will access the same table. The newer application use a standard naming convention. The old application still need to be able to access the data using the old column name until I get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a view.  You can define the view as:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, `old` as `new`
    from `table` t;
```

Assuming no naming conflict, this will give you both.

Now, you might want to go a step further.  You can rename the old table and have the view take the name of the old table:

```
rename table `table` to `old_table`;
create view t as
    select t.*, `old` as `new`
    from `old_table` t;
```

That way, everything that references `table` will start using the view with the new column name.

Comment: Yes, I get your point; however, I would like to create something similar to a view but at the column level, not at the table level like you suggest. The new column name would simply be a persistent alias of the old column name.

Comment: @DrG . . . Some databases support "computed columns", where you can essentially put that definition into the table.  MySQL is not one of those databases, so the view method is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will create a view that rename the old column to new. This will force my new app to use a new table (or my exactly view) name to access the data, but it should work out. Thx